# Heart beat in android

Tags: android, health-monitoring, heartrate

I need to implement Heart Beat on an Android Smartwatch (Android API 23 and Android API 24). The problem is that, according to the *getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL)*, there is nothing such as a Sensor.TYPE_HEART_BEAT or Sensort.TYPE_HEART_RATE. The sensors I can user are

- ACCELEROMETER
- PROXIMITY
- LIGHT
- STEP_COUNTER
- STEP_DETECTOR

It exists a way to implement heart beat/heart rate using proximity and/or light sensor?

Comment: Well, proximity senses how far away something is from the face (screen), and light detects how much light is visible from the face (screen), so unless you can get someone to pull their heart out of their chests and hold it close to the screen so that the beat changes the light level, no.

Comment: @KenWhite what if the sensors are on the back of the smartwatch? They touch the wrist of the user

Comment: What model of the smartwatch has a light sensor on the back? Which one has a proximity sensor on the back? Since both of them deal with external sources, and the back of the watch would not be external to the watch when worn, that wouldn't make much sense. Link to the docs for that watch, please.